# How to count how many is dislike and how many is like?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class ObjectRate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    my_object = models.ForeignKey(Design)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1)
```

`rate` can be set to `-1`(dislike) or `1`(like). How to count how many is dislike and how many is like? (for single object)

views.py:

```
def my_views(request,id):
    my_object = Object.objects.get(id=id)
    votes = ObjectRate.objects.filter(..)
```

What "algorithm" to use?

Answer (score 5):

You can filter `ObjectRate` by `my_object` and `rate` value (either -1 or 1) and get the counts separately:

```
dislikes = ObjectRate.objects.filter(my_object__id=my_object.id, rate=-1).count()
likes = ObjectRate.objects.filter(my_object__id=my_object.id, rate=1).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Aamir answer is good.
But i recommend you user "related_name"

```
class ObjectRate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="rates")
    my_object = models.ForeignKey(Design)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1)
```

then in Your view:

```
def my_views(request,id):
    my_object = User.objects.get(id=id)
    like_votes = my_object.rates.filter(rate=1).count()
    dislike_votes = my_object.rates.filter(rate=-1).count()
```

tip:

is not necessary use "object__id" in django filter, just use the object.
Example:

```
dislikes = ObjectRate.objects.filter(my_object=my_object, rate=-1).count()
likes = ObjectRate.objects.filter(my_object=my_object, rate=1).count()
```